# SSRS what's the difference between using or not First() function for identical data per group?

Tags: reporting-services

If dataset looks like this:

```
ProdictName    Amount    GroupTotal
-----------------------------------
Prod1          10        30
Prod1          20        30
Prod2          10        40
Prod2          20        40
Prod2          30        40
```

Group by ProdictName

We can calculate totals for products like 
`Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)`

Or we can refer to `GroupTotal` column with `First(Fields!GroupTotal.Value)`

Is there any reason to use `First()` function for `GroupTotal` for dataset contents above?

And what will return `Fields!Amount.Value` for `Prod1`? Does it return 10 or 20? What it depends on?

Comment: Normally you would not calculate the group total in your dataset as it's easier and more flexible to do in in the report but either way works...

As four you r more general question, you need to read up on scopes, how aggregations determine which data to aggregate...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-scope-for-totals-aggregates-and-built-in-collections

Comment: I'm using total calculation for group via t-sql only when it's too hard to calculate it thru the formula. Sometimes sum() evaluates incorrect result because of a special kind of data. For examle, column contain number of working days of calculated period and grouping is a Month, i.e. this is a count of working days of this month. And now I'm going to display this to end user. If I'll use sum() for that column, it will show incorrect data and I need to use something like this formula Sum(WorkingDays)/RunningValue(...,CountDistinct...), but why, if I could apply window function in t-sql

Comment: .... as I said,... either way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluating field with or without First() function returns identical result inside one group, i.e. there is only two reasons to use the First() function: to get data from another scope or to get real first value for details group. If you need a first value (not for detail group) from current scope, you can just use Fields!Amount.Value.

It's easy to test - just create a tmp table with few columns whitch you should use as groups and one amount column and fill it with random data. Create a test report based on that tmp table with "order by amount desc". Add a groups in this report and a detail group and add for every group an additional columns with Fields!Amount.Value and First(Fields!Amount.Value) fromulas. Now you can see there is no difference for Fields!Amount.Value and First(Fields!Amount.Value) inside one group.

query for dataset

```js
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
 #rndt;
CREATE TABLE #rndt
(g1     INT
, g2     INT
, g3     INT
, amount DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
DECLARE @cntr1 INT, @cntr2 INT, @cntr3 INT, @cntr4 INT, @cntr1ub INT, @cntr2ub INT, @cntr3ub INT, @cntr4ub INT, @r1 INT, @r2 INT, @r3 INT;
SET @cntr1 = 0;
WHILE @cntr1 < 100
BEGIN
    SET @cntr1 = @cntr1 + 1;
    SET @r1 = ROUND(RAND() * 10000, 0);
    SET @cntr2 = 0;
    SET @cntr2ub = ROUND(RAND() * 10, 0) + 1;
    WHILE @cntr2 < @cntr2ub
        BEGIN
            SET @cntr2 = @cntr2 + 1;
            SET @r2 = ROUND(RAND() * 10000, 0);
            SET @cntr3 = 0;
            SET @cntr3ub = ROUND(RAND() * 10, 0) + 1;
            WHILE @cntr3 < @cntr3ub
                BEGIN
                    SET @cntr3 = @cntr3 + 1;
                    SET @r3 = ROUND(RAND() * 10000, 0);
                    SET @cntr4 = 0;
                    SET @cntr4ub = ROUND(RAND() * 10, 0) + 1;
                    WHILE @cntr4 < @cntr4ub
                        BEGIN
                            SET @cntr4 = @cntr4 + 1;
                            INSERT INTO #rndt
                                   SELECT
                                          @r1
                                        , @r2
                                        , @r3
                                        , ROUND(RAND() * 100000, 2);
                        END;
                END;
        END;
END;
SELECT
   g1
 , g2
 , g3
 , amount
FROM   #rndt
ORDER BY
     amount DESC;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
 #rndt;
```